# C# - Can you do an array of Regex search patterns?

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I'm a network engineer working with multiple version of Cisco's IOS and need to use multiple regular expression patterns.  Is there a way to build an array of regex patterns?

I've used regex patterns in various other programs, but when I started building this I have 3 pattern formats to search for so far and will be adding more as I go through our network, no doubt.

I've tried the usual:

```
Regex someVariable[] = new Regex();
```

This is currently what I have and would like to clean this up into an array for future loop searches through the patterns or so I can just call them individually as needed someVariable[0], etc.

```
Regex intRegex = new Regex(@"((?<!\S)[A-Za-z]{2}\d{1,5}\S+\s+)|(\s[A-Za-z]{7,15}\d{1,5}\S+\s+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Regex psRegex = new Regex(@", id\s+\d{10},", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Regex cidRegex = new Regex(@"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Regex vcidRegex = new Regex(@"vcid\s\d{10},", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I'm not sure what my options are with c# as I've never walked down this path with c# before and in the past have only ever used 1 or maybe 2 Regex search patterns in an entire program before.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. Define a `List<Regex>`, then `.Add` as many regexps as you need. Then, iterate over them when looking for matches.

Comment: If you make a LIst<KeyValuePair<string,string>>  and make the key the variable name and the value the regex pattern you can enumerate through the list.

Comment: Maybe you can try to  use ```Dictionary<string,Regex>```,add like ```dic.Add(key,regex)```,you can get regex by key like ```dic[key]```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Regex[] regexCollection = new Regex[4];

    Regex intRegex = new Regex(@"((?<!\S)[A-Za-z]{2}\d{1,5}\S+\s+)|(\s[A-Za-z]{7,15}\d{1,5}\S+\s+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex psRegex = new Regex(@", id\s+\d{10},", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex cidRegex = new Regex(@"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex vcidRegex = new Regex(@"vcid\s\d{10},", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    regexCollection[0] = intRegex;
    regexCollection[1] = psRegex;
    regexCollection[2] = intRegex;
    regexCollection[3] = vcidRegex;
```

Comment: Honestly I'm so new to C# I had no idea.  Thank you for the syntax help.  I'll give this a build/test.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Got to test it out - this worked exactly as I needed for my program design so just wanted to thank you again and let you know.